# Connectivity of the space of simple $n$-polylines in the plane

Tags: reference-request, connectedness, plane-curves, plane-geometry, path-connected

Given $n\geq1$ and points $p\neq q\in\mathbb R^2$, consider the $2(n-1)$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal M_{p,q}^n$ of simple, non-degenerate polylines from $p$ to $q$ having $n$ segments. By "simple" I mean a polyline does not intersect itself. By "non-degenerate" I mean the $n+1$ vertices of a polyline are all different. (On the other hand, it *is* allowed for consecutive segments to be collinear.)

What is known about $\mathcal M_{p,q}^n$? Is it connected? What if the polylines are restricted to a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, such as the half-space bounded by the line between $p$ and $q$?

I'd love to get a reference that might address my follow-up questions, too!

Comment: Not the same thing, but there are such results for polylines with fixed lengths of segments, see [Geometry and Topology of Polygonail Linkages](https://www.csun.edu/~ctoth/Handbook/chap9.pdf).

Comment: Closer: under the _discrete curve shortening flow_, with fixed ends, such a polyline converges to a line segment. Source: a [high school research project](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/conf/7-1-Cohen-Singh.pdf) (well it's from the PRIMES program so probably correct). Unfortunately they don't say if self-intersections can arise in the process, or where the proof may be found.

Comment: @Desire: The result about linkages with fixed side-lengths implies connectivity for linkages with non-fixed side-lengths (by reducing the problem to the one with the linkage is contained in a straight line). In fact, I think the space is even contractible (modulo rotations).

Comment: @MoisheCohen I don't see how; since a generic linkage with fixed lengths and _fixed ends_ (as in this problem) will not have any configuration  where all edges are collinear.

Comment: @Desire: Just rescale!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M_p^n$ denote the space of all simple polylines $L$ with $n$ segments and the initial vertex at $p$. Let $G$ denote the Lie group of Euclidean similarities (compositions of rotations and dilations) fixing $p$. This group acts on $M_p^n$ freely: $gL=L$ implies $g=e$ for every $g\in G$.

For every fixed $q\ne p$, the submanifold $M_{p,q}^n$ forms a cross-section for the action of $G$ on $M_p^n$:
$$
M_p^n=\bigcup_{g\in G} g M_{p,q}^n. 
$$
Hence, the map
$$
(g,L)\mapsto gL
$$
is a homeomorphism 
$$
G\times M_{p,q}^n\to M_p^n. 
$$
Therefore, it suffices to prove connectivity of  $M_p^n$. The proof is an induction on $n$. For $n=1$ everything is clear, so assume that connectivity holds for $n-1$ and let's prove it for $n$.

Consider a polyline $L\in M_p^n$; it is a concatenation the concatenation of the edges
$$
e_1 * ... * e_{n-1} * e_n.
$$
If the last edge $e_n=[p_{n},p_{n+1}]$ is sufficiently short then, with one exception, for every rotation $R$ around $p_n$, the  polyline
$$
e_1 * ... * e_{n-1} * R(e_n)
$$ 
is still simple. The only exceptional rotation for which this fails is the rotation $R_0$ such that $R_0(e_n)\cap e_{n-1}\ne \{p_n\}$.

Thus, I will do the following. First, scale $e_n$ so that the new edge $e_n'=[p_n,p_{n+1}']$ is sufficiently short. Then apply a rotation $R$ around $p_n$ to the edge $e_n'$ so that the edges $e_{n-1}, R(e_{n}')$ are  collinear and intersect only at $p_n$. Now, set $e'_{n-1}:= e_{n-1}\cup R(e_n')$ (a line segment) and form a new polyline $L'$ as the concatenation
$$
e_1 * ... * e_{n-2} * e'_{n-1}\in M_{p}^{n-1}.
$$
Lastly, use connectivity of $M_{p}^{n-1}$. qed

Remark. An alternative proof can be given by appealing to a much harder theorem, the solution of the "Carpenter's Ruler Problem" (CRP), mentioned by Desire. Namely, choose a positive vector ${\mathbf a}=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and consider the space 
$$
M^n_p({\mathbf a})
$$ 
consisting of simple polylines $L\in M^n_p$ whose side-lengths are fixed to be $a_1,...,a_n$. Then the solution of the CRP shows that   $M_{p}^{n}({\mathbf a})$ is connected. Fix a point $q\in E^2 -\{p\}$. Given a path $L_t, t\in [0,1]$ in $M^n_p({\mathbf a})$, where the polyline $L_t$ terminates at $q_t\in E^2$, let $g_t\in G$ denote the unique similarity (fixing $p$) such that $g_t(q_t)=q$. By uniqueness, $g_t$ depends continuously on $t$. Hence, we obtain a path
$$
g_t L_t\in M^n_{p,q}, t\in [0,1].
$$ 
Taking $L_t$ such that $L_0=L$ and $L_1$ lies on a straight line, we obtain a continuous path $g_tL_t$ connecting $L$ to a linear polyline from $p$ to $q$. 
Proving  that the space of simple linear polylines from $p$ to $q$ is contractible is an easy exercise as it is naturally homeomorphic to the following open simplex
$$
\{{\mathbf a}=(a_1,...,a_n): a_1+...+a_n=1, a_1>0,..., a_n>0\}.
$$

**Edit.** Two more things:

1. A minor modification of the first proof shows that the space of simple polylines in $M^n_{p,q}(E^k)$ (with fixed end-points) in the Euclidean space $E^k$, is also connected. A bit more work shows that this space of polylines is contractible.
2. A cute (and not immediate) property of the subset $C^n_{p,q}({\mathbf a})$ of *strictly convex* simple polylines in $M^n_{p,q}({\mathbf a})$ (in the plane), is that it  consists of exactly two contractible components (obtained from each other by reflecting polylines in the straight line $(pq)$).   Here a polyline is *strictly convex* if it is a convex polygonal curve such that all the edges $e_1,...,e_n$ are non-collinear.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Notice that the question was about polylines on the Euclidean plane, so there are no such rotations. When you increase the dimension (as in my remark at the end), of course, you get a nontrivial stabilizer, so a more refined argument is needed (but the conclusion remains the same).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: If you are interested in the more general argument (contractibility for the space of simple polylines in $E^k$), let me know or, better, ask a separate question since this one was dormant for over  1.5 years. Incidentally, this area of research (geometry and topology of Euclidean polygons) is quite fascinating and connects to several areas of pure math (e.g. Kahler and symplectic geometry, toric varieties, representation theory), random knot theory, robotics, math physics and even math biology.